# Limit a lambda expression to a simple property

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

The signature of my method is

```
void Sample<TData>(Expression<Func<TData,TValue>> expression) { }
```

I want to allow calls like:

```
Sample <MyData>(m => m.SomeProperty);
```

But not

```
Sample<MyData>(m => m.ComplexProperty.AnotherProperty);
```

I tried to count the number of nested bodies and limit the expression to those with a nesting count of 1, but this fails when 'SomeProperty' is derived from a base class.

```
private static int ItemCount(Expression lambaExpression)
{
    int itemCount = 0;
    var member = lambaExpression as MemberExpression;
    while (member != null)
    {
        itemCount += 1;
        member = member.Expression as MemberExpression;
    }
    return itemCount;
}
```

My question is: How do I distinguish between 'Foo.Bar' and 'Foo.Bar.Bar'?

Comment: Even if this is totally legal to do with Expression. From a developers and users point of view it's suspect to this like that. You provide a function that accepts a Expression that can be everything and thats also what I, as a developer, would expect and afterwords you restrict it in extrem manner. I would suggest to write a an extra class for this that users of this function know how they are limited

Comment: @ckruczek A limitation like this is quite common in fluent interfaces (yes, it is quite ugly when you notice it :-) )

Comment: @ckruczek: I am writing a sample framework and want to encourage the users to follow the Law of Demeter.

Comment: @xanatos Yes I am aware of this and I know this technique as well, anyway its very confusing when using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this:

```
public static void Sample<TData, TValue>(Expression<Func<TData, TValue>> expression) 
{
    var body = expression.Body;
    var par1 = expression.Parameters[0];

    MemberExpression member = body as MemberExpression;

    if (member == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    if (member.Expression != par1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    // Success
}
```

You simply check that the `Expression` property of the `MemberExpression` is the parameter (`par1`) of the lambda expression.

Comment: Oh? Parameters[]? Did I miss that? Thanks a lot. I will give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, it sems as if the solution does not work for a property which is declared in a base class but accessed from a derived class.

Comment: @alzaimar An example?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. My unit test was wrong, not your Code. Everything works as expected. Thanks a lot for your help.